# Java imitate default parameter in function

Tags: java, android, function, methods

I have the following functions:

```
public BottomSheetBuilder addItem(int id, @StringRes int title, @DrawableRes int icon) {
   return addItem(id, mContext.getString(title), ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, icon));
}

public BottomSheetBuilder addItem(int id, @StringRes int title, Drawable icon) {
   return addItem(id, mContext.getString(title), icon);
}

public BottomSheetBuilder addItem(int id, String title, @DrawableRes int icon) {
   return addItem(id, title, ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, icon));
}

public BottomSheetBuilder addItem(int id, String title, Drawable icon) {
   mAdapterBuilder.addItem(id, title, icon, mItemTextColor, mItemBackground, mIconTintColor);
   return this;
}
```

I have to add a third parameter of type Boolean.

If this parameter is equal to true or nothing is passed, then null, then it should add the element.

If it is false, it must not be added.

Ex:

```
.addItem(0, "0", null)
.addItem(1, "1", null, false)
.addItem(2, "2", null, true)
.addItem(3, "3", null, false)
```

Some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, there is no default value for a method parameter in java. You either must declare a new method without this parameter, that calls it's "brother" like

```
public void methodA() {
    methodA(true); // default is true
}

public void methodA(boolean param) {
    // do stuff ...
```

Or, since Java 8, you can use the `Optional<T>` class as parameter, which can hold a value, or can be empty (then you handle it like a default value). But then you always need to call the method with the optional parameter, even if you wish to call the defaul one `Optional.empty()`

A im not a fan of `Optional`, but if you have many methods and would not like to double it's amount, maybe this `Optional` class would be a better choice for you.

```
public BottomSheetBuilder addItem(int id, @StringRes int title, @DrawableRes int icon, Optional<Boolean> add)
```

Comment: If you're going to do the optional thing, you may as well just have a 4 parameter version, since you'll always be passing in 4 arguments anyway.  Or pass an object and use null to mean "default".

Comment: Indeed, that's why I am not a fan of it, but you don't need to have any value to call the method (you don't care about the value of the parameter when calling it)

Answer (score 0):

There are no default parameters in Java.  What you need to do is create two versions of each function-  one with 3 parameters, one with 4.  The 3 parameter one calls the 4 parameter one with the "default" value for the 4th parameter.  There isn't really a shortcut.

If you did this a lot you could look at writing an annotation parser that could look for an annotation and automatically add the 3 parameter version based on the existance of the annotation on the function.  But given that's a few hours of work if you know how to write an annotation parser, it isn't worth it.